Visual backgrounds default to white
When I try to copy my visuals as an image, the background always defaults to white. Has anyone had this issue before?
Here is what I have tried so far

Copy image
Copy image with caption
Visualizations -> General -> Effects -> background -> set a hex code with transparency 0%
Visualizations -> Format visual -> Plot area background -> set an image as the background
View -> Themes -> Customize current theme -> Advanced -> Set "Background elements"
View -> Themes -> Customize current theme -> Visuals -> Background
View -> Themes -> Customize current theme -> Page -> Wallpaper
View -> Themes -> Customize current theme -> Page -> Page background

